# Using ASP.Net Core 2.0 Identity Login Application to Authenticate an ASP.Net MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-core

I have a few older .Net 4.0 web applications that I have since updated to 4.7.1. They all connect to a SSO Login using Membership. I have created a new Login application using .Net Core 2.0 Identity and I am trying to connect to my old applications and replicate the authentication they got from Membership.

I have followed the guide and sample code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

I added Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop and setup my Startup.Auth with cookie authentication. I removed the Membership pieces from my web configs, and added:

`<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />`

I am currently at a spot where my connecting applications will redirect to the login page I have specified in my Startup.Auth class. Once on my login, I am able to login successfully, but the redirect back to my application does not occur. I know that my login application is successfully redirecting to the ReturnUrl from testing it explicitly in debug.

It appears I am logging in, redirecting back to my application, but being denied access through the new cookie authentication, so it calls my login page again. It appears to be an issue with the way I have set up my cookie authentication in 1 or both apps.

**Login Startup.cs**

```
 //setup applicaitoncookie
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
         //Cookie settings
         options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
         options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

         //Cookie Name 
         options.Cookie.Name = "COOKIENAME";

          //path for Login is /Account/Login
          options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";

          //path for Access Denied is /Account/AccessDenied
          options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";

          options.SlidingExpiration = true;   
      });

     services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(
           new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\d$\KeyRing"))
           .SetApplicationName("Login");
```

**Application Startup.Auth**

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
      AuthenticationType = "Identity.Application",
      CookieName = "COOKIENAME",
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index"),
      Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
      {
           OnApplyRedirect = ApplyRedirect,
           OnValidateIdentity = 
           SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, 
           ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => 
                user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
       },
       TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
            new DataProtectorShim(
                 DataProtectionProvider.Create(GetKeyRingDirInfo(),
                 (builder) => { 
                     builder.SetApplicationName("Login"); })
                     .CreateProtector(
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
       "Identity.Application",
       "v2"))),
        CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager()
    });

private DirectoryInfo GetKeyRingDirInfo()
{
     var projectDirectoryInfo = new 
         DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\d$\KeyRing");

     return projectDirectoryInfo;
 }

 private static void ApplyRedirect(CookieApplyRedirectContext context)
 {
       Uri absoluteUri;

       if (Uri.TryCreate(context.RedirectUri, UriKind.Absolute, out 
       absoluteUri))
       {
            var path = PathString.FromUriComponent(absoluteUri);
            if (path == context.OwinContext.Request.PathBase + 
                 context.Options.LoginPath)
            {
                 context.RedirectUri = 
                 "http://localhost/VS_2017/Login/Account/Login" +
                        new QueryString(
                            context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter,
                            "?ReturnUrl=/VS_2017/Application");
             }
        }

        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
   }
```

I have tried with and without OnApplyRedirect, but the only way I found to direct the user to my Login application without using the FormsAuthentication webconfig for Membership was to use the Redirect URL.

I am successfully creating the cookie COOKIENAME and it is encrypted in my browser. I think I may be missing something on the web application side where I am not correctly calling my Login application and authenticating the cookie it creates.

Any help with where I may be going wrong, or where to look next would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!